# Why when adding to the listview items the result is not the file name?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm searching in a directory in *.cs files for specific string.
If there is a result i'm adding it to a listview.
But when it's adding the result to the listview i don't see the CS file name the string was found in but something else.

In the backgroundworker dowork event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            FindLines(@"d:\c-sharp", "simplecontextmenu");//"string s1 = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as string;");
        }
```

This is the FindLines code

```
bool result = false;
        public List<string> FindLines(string DirName, string TextToSearch)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            List<string> findLines = new List<string>();
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(DirName);

            List<FileInfo> l = new List<FileInfo>();
            CountFiles(di, l);

            int totalFiles = l.Count;
            int countFiles = 0;
            if (di != null && di.Exists)
            {
                if (CheckFileForAccess(DirName) == true)
                {
                    foreach (FileInfo fi in l)
                    {
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress((int)((double)countFiles / totalFiles * 100.0), fi.Name);
                        countFiles++;
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

                        if (string.Compare(fi.Extension, ".cs", true) == 0)
                        {
                            using (StreamReader sr = fi.OpenText())
                            {
                                string s = "";
                                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    if (s.Contains(TextToSearch))
                                    {
                                        counter++;
                                        findLines.Add(s);
                                        result = true;
                                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, s);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return findLines;
        }
```

And this is the backgroundworker progresschanged event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label2.Text = e.UserState.ToString();
            if (result == true)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(e.UserState.ToString());
                result = false;
            }
        }
```

Something with the ReportProgress in the FindLines method and with the e.UserState in the progresschanged event is wrong. I don't get the path and name of the cs file the string was found in in the listview.

I'm searching in this directory for the string "simplecontextmenu" and if the string is in any of the cs files in the directory i want to add to the listview the file name where the string was found in with the directory for example if the string was found in test.cs then in listview show me:

c:\mytest\test.cs         "simplecontextmenu"

But what i get instead is the line it self from the code what i see in the listview is this: FindLines(@"d:\c-sharp", "simplecontextmenu");//"string s1 = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as string;");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reporting the matching line `s` in the `backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, s);`. You should be reporting the file name instead:

`backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, fi.FullName);`